# Kademlia bucketing

Tags: java, bitwise

[Kademlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) is a DHT (distributed hash table) which uses a specific type of routing table, dependent on the Hamming distance between the "addresses" of two peers on the network. I'm attempting to implement a modified version of it in Java. To find which "bucket" in the routing table a peer should go into, I xor the peer's address with my client's address and try to find the index of the first true bit in the result. So far I've been using this code:

```
    private int findBucket(byte[] address) {
        byte[] xorresult = xor(nodeAddress, address);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int temp = toBinaryString(xorresult[i]).indexOf('1');

            if (temp != -1) {
                return (i * 8) + temp;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static String toBinaryString(byte n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
            if (((n >> bit) & 1) > 0) {
                sb.setCharAt(7 - bit, '1');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the java.util.BitSet? It has build in xor(), nextSetBit() and conversion from/to byte[].

Comment: @user158037 I have no control over the inputs, they have to be byte arrays. I had a previous version of this code that converted the arrays to bitsets, but not only was that version (much) slower, the bitsets had a tendency to not keep the imposed 160 bit size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has some useful functions to search for set bits in the [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class, including [numberOfLeadingZeros](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(int)). Of course, being in the `Integer` class (and there is no equivalent in the `Byte` class), it counts the leading zeros of an `int` instead of a `byte`, so it returns 24 too much. That's easy to work around by subtracting 24 though, and using this function means we can get rid of the function that converts a byte to a string.

I would also avoid allocating a temporary array just to hold the XORed addresses, it just doesn't seem to add much to the code, and I would also make it more explicit that 20 is indeed the size of the array and not some arbitrary number.

So you can write it like this:

```
private int findBucket(byte[] address) {
    for (int i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        int temp = (address[i] ^ nodeAddress[i]) & 0xFF;

        if (temp != 0) {
            return i * 8 + Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(temp) - 24;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```